# Does CODEOWNERS inherit owners

Tags: github

Consider the following CODEOWNERS file:

```
*             @username1
/subfolder/   @username2
```

Now if a change is made to `/subfolder/somefile.txt`... Will only `@username2` get added as a reviewer OR would both `@username1` and `@username2`?

PS: Testing this would require me to create three accounts (mine to make the edit, username1 and username2 to test) - AND - this information should be publically available for future searchers. I couldn't find this example covered [in the official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners).

Would like an example or a document reference to be sure or answer correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only @username2 will be added as a reviewer. Since the order in which you place the patterns is important. It tries to take the last match.

In the docs they give [an example](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#example-of-a-codeowners-file) of a CODEOWNERS file, and they try to explain with an example how inheritance works.

Comment: Got it `These owners will be the default owners for everything in the repo. Unless a later match takes precedence` So basically "no inheritance", I kept searching for a feature that isn't :D